# MySQL Server shuts down frequently and won't start again now

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

**OS:** Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS xenial

I installed MySQL on my server on AWS and it was working fine, but after we started getting much traffic on-site, it started failing frequently. To fix it, I usually restart the service or server which works but for only a few minutes/hours and then it fails again. Now MySQL doesn't start again even after I restart the server.

Running `sudo systemctl start mysql` i get this message

> Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

And this is the content logged in `/var/log/mysql/error.log`

```
2017-02-08T11:35:32.352942Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)
2017-02-08T11:35:32.352975Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)
2017-02-08T11:35:32.509812Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-02-08T11:35:32.510752Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) starting as process 3060 ...
2017-02-08T11:35:32.514030Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2017-02-08T11:35:32.514046Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-02-08T11:35:32.514049Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2017-02-08T11:35:32.514054Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2017-02-08T11:35:32.514057Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2017-02-08T11:35:32.514060Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2017-02-08T11:35:32.514265Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2017-02-08T11:35:32.514359Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-02-08T11:35:32.515647Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2017-02-08T11:35:32.522465Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-02-08T11:35:32.524160Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2017-02-08T11:35:32.535815Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-02-08T11:35:32.536689Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 30903245
2017-02-08T11:35:32.536703Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 30904484
2017-02-08T11:35:32.536738Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Ignoring the redo log due to missing MLOG_CHECKPOINT between the checkpoint 30903245 and the end 30904484.
2017-02-08T11:35:32.536747Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2017-02-08T11:35:33.137801Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2017-02-08T11:35:33.137835Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2017-02-08T11:35:33.137841Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2017-02-08T11:35:33.137843Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2017-02-08T11:35:33.137848Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2017-02-08T11:35:33.137893Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2017-02-08T11:35:33.137914Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2017-02-08T11:35:33.138111Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Still don't know what went wrong but deleting the files `/var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile*` solved it.

Comment: I had this issue within Docker Compuse, and to access the files, I ran: `docker-compose run --rm db /bin/bash` (where `db` is your database service), then deleting the files from there.

Comment: I'm troubled the whole day. You saved me. This answer works well for the error from /var/log/mysql/error.log: [ERROR] InnoDB: Ignoring the redo log due to missing MLOG_CHECKPOINT between the checkpoint 30903245 and the end 30904484.

Comment: It solved my issue but it would be nice to know what went wrong

Comment: God bless you !

Comment: Same worked for me

Answer (score 0):

please try the following

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
service mysql stop
sudo killall -KILL mysql mysqld_safe mysqld
/etc/init.d/mysql start
systemctl status mysql
```

And it should show active status for the mysql server